# converge / over monadic function leads to scope error

Tags: kdb

I cant see to put converge (/) inside the function:

```
 i:0
 arg:0
 {x+:1;i+:1}/[{i~0};0]
 i ' Leads to answer 1
```

Works where i comes out to 1. The following segment will return an error:

```
   depp:{[arg] i:0;  {x+:1;i+:1}/[{i~0};0]; :i}
   depp[0] ' Cant recognize i
```

Why?

Answer (score 3):

you will either have to pass i to the `lambda`inside the function `depp` or use global assignment for `i` i.e

```
depp:{[arg] i::0;  {x+:1;i+:1}/[{i~0};0]; :i}
```